# Any workaround to disable the red warning message on the react-admin login page?

Tags: react-admin

If you go here https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo

You can see an error message in red at the bottom of the screen.

This is not a nice experience for the first page of an app.

Is there any hack to disable it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In our case we're creating a custom AuthProvider, and then we can specify that we don't want the error red message at the bottom, when we reject the Promise in the checkAuth method:

```
const checkAuth = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem(appConfig.browser.localStorageKeys.auth)) {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    return Promise.reject({ message: false });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this behavior can be disabled by removing the autoFocus property of input in [Login.tsx](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/7223b233ce17f8ffaf8e7c3cd955615f539594d6/examples/demo/src/layout/Login.tsx#L137).

```
<Field
    autoFocus // remove this
    name="username"
    // @ts-ignore
    component={renderInput}
    label={translate('ra.auth.username')}
    disabled={loading}
/>
```

Comment: I'm not talking about the red message below the email input.
I'm talking about about the notify message at the very bottom of the screen.
This workaround does not work, I just tested it.
Also, autoFocus on email is a nice feature.

Comment: I misunderstood. I examined my react-admim application and "please login to continue" notification didn't show up. I followed this advanced tutorial https://github.com/marmelab/ra-example-oauth/ to make my login page contained 3 inputs. Simply I made LoginForm (without react-final form) and wrapped it with Login component of react-admin. 

Note: This disables "please login to continue" notification from every path you are redirected.

Answer (score 0):

The login page which u r seeing is a default page provided inside the react admin. You can make your own login page and use the data provider to authenticate and also you can use different Component to show the message or can have your own component and invoke them at the autherr on authentication provider.

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html
check the

> Customizing The Login and Logout Components

You may find a solution from here.